# Do console.log or alerts work in a webview inside a kindle fire app through ddms

Tags: javascript, debugging, kindle

Do webviews running in a kindle fire app (also on a kindle fire HD) support javascript console.log or alerts?

I have my kindle fire HD connected through usb debugging and ddms to my computer, and I'm seeing lots of log data but no messages from a webview where my javascript code is calling both alert('alert test') and console.log('log test');

I'm surprised how little information there is, even in the phonegap forums. It's like I'm the first person to ever have to troubleshoot javascript running in a webview on a kindle fire app, which seems strange since the hardware has been out for a while.

Comment: You can test it like `if(console == undefined) alert('No Console!');`

Comment: I can't even get an alert to work, and I can't find any info if console.log or alert are even supported.

Comment: You might want to look at this:
http://log4js.berlios.de/

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I might use a logging solution, but that doesn't answer my question. I'm trying to determine if webviews support console.log or alerts on the kindle fire HD. I reworded my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

My own testing on a kindle fire HD system version 7.2.3 shows:

Web (silk): support for alert() but no support for console.log() (even when hooked up to adb/ddms)

Webview: no support for alert() and no support for console.log() (even when hooked up to adb/ddms)

Wish I could find more information on debugging webview applications on the kindle fire. I'll be trying out some javascript based logging solutions instead.

edit: used jsconsole successfully on a kindle fire HD to retrieve console.log messages and run javascript on the fly. http://jsconsole.com